# Bootstrap 4. Как на несколько размеров экранов поставить invisible?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Bootstrap 4 - версия которую я использую.
У меня есть два изображения. Первое и второе правильно отображается на md, lg и xl.
Как мне задать класс div, что-бы фотографии не отображались на типах xs и sm ? Просто сложить:

```
d-none d-sm-block
```

И

```
d-sm-none d-md-block
```

чтобы выходило:

```
 d-none d-sm-block d-sm-none d-md-block
```

не выходит(т.к есть противоречивые элементы)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как мне задать класс div, что-бы фотографии не отображались на типах xs и sm ?

`d-none d-md-block`